# Knockout observablearray thows undefined error

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am getting undefined error while pushing new values into a array.

html:

```
 <select id="temp" data-bind="options:Original"></select>
 <select data-bind="options:dynamicaarry"></select>
```

viewModel:

```
var ViewModal=function(items) {
    this.dynamicaarry=ko.observableArray(items);
    this.Original=ko.observableArray(['volvo','saab','mercedes','audi']);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModal(['four']));
$("#temp").change(function() {
    this.ViewModal.dynamicaarry.push('six'); //throws undefined error});});
}
```

And is it possible to handle selectedindexchange event in knockout without using jquery ?

Comment: You need to understand the 'this' keyword in javascript: http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/

Comment: The link was very informative . Thank budy

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call ViewModal in different context. So, first of all, you should remove `this` from change event handler, and the second, you shouldn't use jQuery change event handler, you should to use knockout binding, instead:

Html:

```
<select id="temp" data-bind="options:Original, event: { change: changeOriginal }"></select>
```

ViewModel:

```
var ViewModal=function(items) {
    this.dynamicaarry=ko.observableArray(items);
    this.Original=ko.observableArray(['volvo','saab','mercedes','audi']);

    this.changeOriginal = function() {
        this.ViewModal.dynamicaarry.push('six');
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModal(['four']));
```